# How can I write code that works with the JSON API differences in MarkLogic 7 and 8?

Tags: json, xquery, marklogic

MarkLogic 8 improves JSON support in many ways, but some of the MarkLogic 7 JSON functions now have different signatures or do different things. How can I write XQuery code that works with both releases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So far the main changes I've run into are to `xdmp:from-json`, `xdmp:to-json`, and `json:transfrom-to-json`. If you have a fair amount of JSON-related code from MarkLogic 7, these changes may break existing code.

Instead of calling those `xdmp` and `json` functions directly, import this library module and call `c:from-json`, etc. This allows code written for MarkLogic 7 to work in both releases.

```
module namespace c="http://blakeley.com/marklogic/json/compatibility";

import module namespace json="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json"
 at "/MarkLogic/json/json.xqy";

(: No prefix for the fn:* functions :)
declare default function namespace "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions";

declare variable $VERSION := xs:integer(
  substring-before(xdmp:version(), ".")) ;

declare function c:from-json(
  $arg as xs:string)
as item()*
{
  xdmp:from-json(
    if ($VERSION ge 8) then xdmp:unquote($arg, (), "format-json")
    else $arg)
};

declare function c:to-json(
  $item as item()*)
as xs:string*
{
  if ($VERSION ge 8) then xdmp:quote($item)
  else xdmp:to-json($item)
};

declare function c:transform-to-json(
  $node as node(),
  $config as map:map?)
as xs:string
{
  json:transform-to-json($node, $config) ! (
    if ($VERSION ge 8) then xdmp:quote(.)
    else .)
};

declare function c:transform-to-json(
  $node as node())
as xs:string
{
  c:transform-to-json($node, ())
};
```

I'll extend this as I run into other changes or hear about them. If it gets too long I'll move it to a gist or a github project.

Comment: ML8 release notes lists all incompatibilities: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/relnotes/chap4#id_92312